# When to send Laravel notifications (prevent duplicates)

Tags: notifications, laravel-8

My project uses the native Laravel notifications (stored in a db table). I want to send a notification to all users when a new article is created, however the article model has a boolean attribute 'published', so I only want to send the notifications when a new article has been created *and* this attribute has been set to true.

So using an observer to send the messages when a new article is created is not going to work, because it has nog been published at that point. Another option is listening to the 'updated' event and sending notifications when the 'published' attribute is true, but only the first save, otherwise you keep sending notifications on each save.

The only solution seems to be to keep track of what notifications are sent for each related model, but it's hard to use the notification table to do this, since you have to use a json object to store a reference to the related model. So what's the best practice? Creating additional columns to the notification table? Creating a seperate table for this?

Answer (score 0):

Specifically to your issue I'd check if the field `published` is dirty when the attribute is about to be updated. Because, if it's already posted, then that state won't change so it will basically ignore all subsequent updates. You can do this like so:

```php
class PostObserver
{
    // ...

    public function updating(Post $post)
    {
      if($post->isDirty('published')){
        // status has been changed -> fire notification
        Notification::send(User::all(), new PostPublished($post));
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not unlikely to set the article to published, then realize some issues, unpublish it, and publish it again later. You would have duplicate notifications at that point.

Comment: Then just add a new column in your post table to keep track of all notified posts

Comment: Yes that's possible, but then you'll have to do the same for every model you want to send notifications to, if that's the only option, then sure, but I was hoping there was some more elegant option.

Comment: If there's multiple models to check, then create a polymorphic relationship and store in that table the related column. This way, you will have only one table with all model published states